# sqlite3_get_table - testing for existence of table?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have the following code, and sql string in which my errors have been solved on another post. 
Basically, this function tests whether a table exists or not.. That's it.

I'm posted the relevant section below.. For some reason, even if the table doesn't exist in the database, my function always tells me that the table exists?

Any clues as to what I've done wrong here.. Could it be the way I'm using the return value of sqlite3_get_table?

```
string sql_string =  "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name='test_table';";




   // open database

dbase_return = sqlite3_open_v2(dbase_path.c_str(),&DBHANDLE,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,NULL);

 if(!dbase_return)
    {

   dbase_return_tbl = sqlite3_get_table(DBHANDLE,sql_string.c_str(),&result,&row,&column,&error_msg);



        if(dbase_return_tbl==SQLITE_OK)
        { 
            cout << " Table exists" << endl;
            sqlite3_close(DBHANDLE);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {

            cout << "Table doesn't exists" << endl;
           sqlite3_close(DBHANDLE);
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens if you execute the same SQL on the command line?

Comment: You would get an error code from `sqlite3_get_table` if the query were syntactically malformed (or some other error occurred). A well-formed query that happens to produce zero rows is perfectly valid, not an error condition.

Comment: I see what you mean. It was my interpretation of get_table that was wrong then.